# Oracle varchar not equal statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm creating an app, and in some point I need to select data from database, but I cannot build the SQL for this situation.

```
column1         | column2 | column3
tom .......     | xxx     | xxx
tom_sp1         | xxx     | xxx
tom_sp2         | xxx     | xxx
kim  ........   | xxx     | xxx
tommy   ..      | xxx     | xxx
bruce ....      | xxx     | xxx
bruce_sp1       | xxx     | xxx
```

Not the best table ever I know (:

So I need to create SQL which shouldn't show '_sp(number)' rows, so output should be show just tom,kim, tommy,and bruce (not tom_sp1, tom_sp2, and  bruce_sp1).

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: What part is causing you difficulty?

Comment: Can not create SQL statement. I'm not sure how to build where clause.

Comment: what about `where column1 not like '%_sp%'`?

Comment: Thank you Dan, but if I use '%_sp%' It could get anything after 'sp', I just want number after 'sp'. So that will not show xxx_split, but I want to see xxx_split or something include _sp.. except _sp(numbers)

Comment: @DanBracuk, with `like`, `_` is a wild card character that matches one of any character. So `'asp' not like '%_sp%'` is false. To match an underscore, `'asp' not like '%\_sp%' escape '\'`. That doesn't solve the number issue though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how exact you need to be.

If you want to exclude rows where `column1` *ends* with the string "_sp" followed by a number of any length, then this would do it:

```
select * from my_table where not regexp_like(name,'\_sp[0-9]+$')
```

Comment: `name not like '%\_sp%'` is much simpler.

Comment: But it's not exact.  If the OP is positive that the only occurrences of "_sp" in the column are part of this special tag, then you're right: `not like` would be easier and would run faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, `Like` patterns do not have a default escape character, at least not in Oracle. If an escape character is needed it must be specified with the `escape` keyword, `name not like '%\_sp%' escape '\'`

Answer (score 0):

Read about regular expression in Oracle. Try something like:

CREATE TABLE persons
      (column1 VARCHAR2(1000));

```
INSERT INTO persons (column1) VALUES ('tom');
INSERT INTO persons (column1) VALUES ('tom_sp1');
INSERT INTO persons (column1) VALUES ('tom_sp2');
INSERT INTO persons (column1) VALUES ('kim');
INSERT INTO persons (column1) VALUES ('bruce');
INSERT INTO persons (column1) VALUES ('bruce_sp12');
INSERT INTO persons (column1) VALUES ('bruce_sp12ss');
COMMIT;

SELECT *
  FROM persons
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '_sp[[:digit:]]*');
```